# nginx can't find my files inside a location block

Tags: nginx

I am trying to get nginx to serve a beta version of a angular2 front end replacement of my rails app by navigating to .../beta but I can't seem to get nginx to find any files.

I have tried navigating to ..../beta  ..../beta/index.html, but it never seems to find the index (or any files I put in that directory).

Here is the location block which I know is being matched because with the try_files directive I get routed to my normal rails app whenever I try to go anywhere under beta. (without the try_files I get an nginx 404 reply)

```
  location /beta {
    root /var/www/ourlatitude/angular_dist;
    try_files  $uri $uri/ /;
  }
```

I also know the file exists because I can list the file and see the contents from the script that starts nginx.

```
echo "starting nginx"
ls -l /var/www/ourlatitude/angular_dist/index.html
cat /var/www/ourlatitude/angular_dist/index.html
nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

Here is the output from the script.

```
starting nginx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 900 Apr 15 16:16 /var/www/ourlatitude/angular_dist/index.html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ourlatitude</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">
<link href="styles.c06b2f9217e876bbd94a.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/></head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.1b4e5bfe11db95ba56df.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.1511b33427d0b840a6ea.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.2104002a7ee0b6a6562f.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.8ad811b26786bedbaf91.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

I feel I am missing something really basic here.
Any ideas what might be going on?

I can include more of the nginx config file if that helps.

The only other out of the ordinary thing I am doing is this is all within a docker container,  but I don't *think* that matters.

Comment: Use `alias` instead of `root`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

Comment: @RichardSmith thank you - this works, but have to admit, I don't understand why.  I think I am misreading the doc or something basic, since It seems like root should work.  If you could post this as an answer and explain what is the difference in this case between using root and alias, I will accept it.  Thanks again, I spent so much time yesterday trying so many variations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`root` and `alias` are quite different. The `location` block is there to match a URI, in this case `/beta/index.html`.

The `root` directive determines what prefix to add to the URI, to turn it into a pathname. In your question, that would be `/var/www/ourlatitude/angular_dist/beta/index.html`, which is **not** what you want. The value of the `location` block is only relevant to match the URI, and *not* to construct the pathname.

The `alias` directive within a prefix `location` constructs the pathname by first removing the value of the `location`, so:

```
location /beta {
    alias /var/www/ourlatitude/angular_dist;
    ...
}
```

will match the URI `/beta/index.html`, then remove the `/beta` before prefixing the `/var/www/ourlatitude/angular_dist`, which will construct the pathname: `/var/www/ourlatitude/angular_dist/index.html`.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

Comment: Excelent response.

Answer (score 0):

`alias` directive is called so because it… aliases URI to path in server's filesystem.

`root` defines a… root point in filesystem and all URI's searches are done relative to that root point, under that point.